# Using php expire cookie after 30th visit

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have cookie with useranme "ABC" . How can I set it,such that it would expire after 30th visit.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: its pretty easy to set for a particular time period.I am aware of how to achieve that.But how to do,when we are trying to count the visits .just a hint would do. @Cagy79

Comment: Tip: set a another cookie with parameter as count and increment it

Answer (score 1):

Create two cookies, one for username and another one for maintaing visit count like:

```
setcookie('useranme', 'ABC');
setcookie('visit_count', 1);
```

and increase the visit_count to 1 on every visit. When it crossed the limit, delete the cookie like:

```
unset($_COOKIE['useranme']);
unset($_COOKIE['visit_count']); // or reset its counter to 1 again.
```

Comment: Thanks.that will do the job.awesome @Mayank

Comment: Sounds good! where is the party ? :D

Comment: This all depends on you hitting a certain criteria - e.g. going through a login page. What if this is on a home page and it's refreshed 30 times in a single session - would that not reset it?

Comment: You have to set the condition set for incrementing or expiring the cookie

Comment: Jane please keep the Steve point in mind while implementing the logic